# how to write on file after the text already present int that file (cursor movement to the end of the file)

Tags: java, file, streamwriter, cursor-position

This is my code for reading file and writing file ; i want to write string content to the end of the text file. My aim is to have command on cursor movement/controlling in a text file.

please help me out thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Filing {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String content = "This is the content to write into file";

    BufferedReader br = 
     new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Ashad/Desktop/text.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Ashad/Desktop/text.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 



        while (line != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }

       //** bw.write(content) ; **//

        String everything = sb.toString();

        System.out.append(everything); 
    } 
    finally 
    { br.close();}
```

I couldnot write String content after the text already present on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to write string content to the end of the text file

Then just use the [overload of the `FileWriter` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) that takes an `append` flag:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Ashad/Desktop/text.txt", true);
```

Personally though, I'd prefer to use `FileOutputStream` and an `OutputStreamWriter` - that way you can specify the encoding.

Comment: can you please show me how that works ? how this line can write string at the end of the file ?

Comment: i didnt get overload of filewriter

Comment: @AshadChaudhary: Edited now for clarity - the constructor is overloaded; there's a version which has a `boolean` parameter for whether or not you want to append.

Answer (score 1):

Create the FileWriter in append mode:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Ashad/Desktop/text.txt", true);
```